# Principle of inheritance and dynamic binding not clear

Tags: java, inheritance

I have got a problem to understand inheritance and dynamic binding. I am reading currently a java book for beginners and there is an example in this case.

```
class Parent {
    public String getFoo() { 
        return "parentFoo";
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public String getFoo() {
        return "childFoo";
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return "childBar";
    }
}

class GrandChild extends Child {
    public String getFoo() {
        return "grandChildFoo";
    }
}

Parent p0 = new Child();
p0.getFoo();
p0.getBar();
Child c0 = new GrandChild();
c0.getFoo();
c0.getBar();
GrandChild gc0 = new GrandChild();
gc0.getFoo();
gc0.getBar();
```

I am not understanding what `Parent p0 = new Child();` means. I have searched on the internet and in my book but I am not finding the solution why a `new object` is created here. 
Furthermore, I am not understanding why `p0.getBar();` is giving an error and `p0.getFoo();` not.
I am very thankful for every help!

Cheers mates

Comment: To make things more intuitive, replace Parent with Animal, Child with Mammal and GrandChild with Dog. A Dog is a type of Mammal and Mammal is a type of Animal.

Answer (score 0):

"*I am not understanding what `Parent p0 = new Child();` means.*" - It means that you create a reference of type `Parent` and initialize it with a `Child`. This works because `Child` automatically inherits all attributes and methods from `Parent`, thus a `Child` can be use as if it were a `Parent`. This is sometimes called an "*is-a*" relationship (a `Child` "*is-a*" `Parent`), but I personally refrain from using this term<sup>1</sup>. A more appropriate definition is given by [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

> Liskov's notion of a behavioural subtype defines a notion of substitutability for objects; that is, if `S` is a subtype of `T`, then objects of type `T` in a program may be replaced with objects of type `S` without altering any of the desirable properties of that program (e.g. correctness).

(Note: this is not enforced by the language since we are talking about semantics, and the compiler has no concept of semantics, but is shows that, syntactially, a Subtype - or subclass - is also always of its supertype - or superclass.)

---

"*Furthermore I am not understanding why `p0.getBar();` is giving an error and `p0.getFoo();` not.*" --- `p0` is a `Parent`-reference. Thus, we can only access attributes and mehtods defined in `Parent`. Although the runtime-type of `p0` is, in fact, a `Child`, we cannot access the methods solely defined in `Child`. For this, let us create a small example. Imagine a class `Animal` with one method `sound()`. Now let us imagine two classes `Dog` and `Bird` that extend `Animal`. The `Dog`-class has a method `isBestOfBois()`, while the `Bird`-class has a method `fly()`. We can now write something like this:

```
Animal animal;
if (user selects dog as his animal) {
    animal = new Dog();
} else {
    animal = new Bird();
}
// animal.isBestOfBois(); should not be accessible, since animal could be a Bird
// animal.fly(); should not be accessible since animal could be a Dog
animal.sound(); // Both Dog and Bird are guaranteed to have a method sound, so this is fine.
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>The reason I refrain from using "*is-a*" to describe an inherintance relationship is that it leads to confusion. Is a square a rectangle? Or is a rectangle a square? The mathematician would clearly say that a square is a specialized form of a rectangle, thus all squares should be rectangles, thus in terms of inheritance, `Square` should inherit from `Rectangle`. But, different than a rectangle, a square is defined by only one value (its edge-length), while a rectangle is defined by two (width and height). If a square is a rectangle, and we change the width of a rectangle, is it sensible that also the height changes? Because that would happen in the square-case, and I do not think that this is acceptable behaviour. Thus, in terms of inheritance-relation, `Square` and `Rectangle` should not stand in an inheritance-relationship, even if there is a "*is-a*" relationship between them.</sub>

Comment: Due the reason that (a Child "is-a" Parent) p0 can only use methods which are defined in the class Parent and Child. And a method which is in both classes gets overwritten, like with p0.getFoo();, right? Where you use the method defined in the Child class. Therefore the method has to be in both Classes, if you want to use the method. Otherwise it is not possible to access ist, right?

Comment: "*Due the reason that a (a Child "is-a" Parent) p0 can only use methods which are defined in the class Parent and Child. And a method which is in both classes gets overwritten, like with p0.getFoo();, right?*" - Yes. --- "*Therefore the method has to be in both Classes, if you want to use the method. Otherwise it is not possible to access ist, right?*" - No, the method must be in the `Parent`-class. It can be overwritten in `Child`, but this is not necessary.

Comment: It means that if I write down the exact same method in the Child class nothing gets overwritten and it is just the same method as in the Parent class.

Comment: No. It gets overridden. The compiler is not "smart enough" to see that the methods are identical. If You do not want to override, do not override. Then, the method gets inherited from the superclass.

Comment: But it is simply the same method in the end, right?

Comment: Depends. I can construct an example where the same code (i.e. a copy-pasted version from `Parent` to `Child`) will result in different output. But normally, yes.

Comment: If I create a reference of type Parent and initialize it with a Child, does that mean that every attribute and method is inherted from the class "Parent"?

Comment: No. It gets inherited because `Child` inherits from `Parent` (`class Child extends Parent { ... }`). Please refrain from asking new questions in the comments.